# Data table multi value column

Tags: tables, data-collection

I have a table containing incoming invoices. I have to show additional information about the sender of the invoice. So I figured out that I can nest Sender name and his Tax ID in one row with quite smaller font. It's OK, but I'm confused about where to put info about what the number below sender name is:

A: [Column header](http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/6842/90447148.png)

B: [Inline label](http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/3977/45216639.png)

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headers **locked**. Option **A** Column header. **Wrap** text, match **font weight** in first column header to reflect the two corresponding lines.

> **Sender        Doc. No.        Doc. Dt.**
>   Tax ID
>
> **Company A**
>   2416935478

Comment: Thak you all for your replies, in my case this will be the most appropriate solution. Thanks

Comment: Nice to be of help.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you go along with alternative A and in the column header you emphasise the Sender text with making it bolder/darker/bigger, as it's presented in the cells for that column. That way a more distinct connection between the parameter type and value is achieved.

Something like this perhaps:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To some extent it depends on whether the header is always visible and how many results are show on the page at one time (how far down from the header has been scrolled).

However, according to the usability principle of reducing memory load, I think a bit of redundancy is okay, so **I would go with B - an inline label with a "downplayed" styling** as you suggest.

From my experience people seldom look at headers, so all the necessary info needs to be contained in the data themselves.

Although being iOS apps, most of the examples in the following align a numeric value with its unit inline (some of them graphically): http://pttrns.com/?scid=18